# Do we know anything else about the calculus problem solved by Rabbi Moshe Feinstein?

Tags: history, moshe-feinstein, mathematics

The biographical sketch of Rabbi Moshe Feinstein that appears [in *Igrot Moshe* volume 8](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=922&st=&pgnum=23) describes the following (my translation):

> The Communist takeover meant the schools taught against religion. Some of the older Jewish students would argue back, citing teachings of their rabbi [Moshe Feinstein]. One infuriated teacher (herself Jewish) finally replied, "What does that rabbi of yours know, if he can't solve this calculus problem?!"
>
> Eventually the problem was brought to Rabbi Feinstein; who requested a calculus textbook, read it, and then solved it.

Have any details about this story (other than the ones printed there) survived to this day?

Comment: Well, the original you paraphrased does imply it's _differential_ calculus.

Comment: I suggest you ask him: http://daattorah.blogspot.com/

Comment: Perhaps this should be asked on Math.SE ;)

Comment: the same story has one version with dozen of Gedolim, rav Aharon Kotler, Chafets Chayim. etc.

Comment: @Kouty the story is printed by Rabbi Feinstein's family, which gives it some decent heft. R' Aharon Kotler very nearly got on a train to leave yeshiva and study mathematics in Moscow, and his sister spent the rest of her life regretting that he didn't do so; I thus find it unlikely that he would solve a Communist's challenge to solve a calculus problem. The Chofetz Chaim? He was rosh yeshiva, not town rabbi, when the communists ruled Radin. So I'd find it unlikely.

Comment: @msh210 It could have been differential equations. I heard that Russian kids are way ahead in math

Comment: ...But I guess they are making the point that it was an easy book anyway? Can't read Hebrew->

Comment: Does anyone know the problem?

Answer (score 6):

There is a very slightly different account [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=3cl2DBMwAwcC&lpg=PA12&ots=OnNt3YgI65&dq=moshe%20feinstein%20calculus&hl=iw&pg=PA12#v=onepage&q&f=false), which places the story in the context of religious persecution and Rav Moshe's ostensible motivations for leaving Russia.

But something tells me by "details about this story" you mean "specific contents of the calculus problem", in which case this is no help. . .